# ‘Creature’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

How to fix error in Hero.h ?

```
 GCC C++ compiler flags  : -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu++11 ;
```

I update g++ to 4.8.1

```
// Creature.h
#pragma once

#ifndef CREATURE_H_
#define CREATURE_H_

#include <string>
#include "Hero.h"
#include "Characteristics.h"
#include <map>

class Creature
{
private:

    CreatureCharacteristics Characters;

    Creature(const std::string i_name, int i_count = 0); 
    Creature(const Creature& Donor);

public:
    typedef std::map < std::string, Creature* > Prototypes;
    static Prototypes Clones_Bank;
    ~Creature();

    const CreatureCharacteristics& Get_characteristics(){
        return this->Characters;
    }

    static Creature*& Clone(std::string i_name, int i_count = 0);
};
#endif /* CREATURE_H_ */


// Hero.h
#pragma once

#ifndef HERO_H_
#define HERO_H_

#include "Creature.h"
#include "Characteristics.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<Creature*> Army; // ERROR HERE (‘Creature’ was not declared in this 
     scope)


class Hero {
private:
    Army                army;
    HeroCharacteristics base_characteristics;

public:
    Hero(std::string name = '\0', int attack = 0, int defense = 0):
        hero_name(name)
    {
        base_characteristics.attack = attack;
        base_characteristics.defence = defense;
    };
    const Army& Get_army() const
    {
        return army;
    };
    const std::string& Get_name() const
    {
        return hero_name;
    };
    const HeroCharacteristics& Get_characteristics() const
    {
        return base_characteristics;
    };
    void Add_creature(Creature* creature, int creature_count);
};
#endif /* HERO_H_ */
```

Comment: excuse me for syntax
it was my first question ))

Comment: Don't include the Creature header in Hero.h. You simply need to do a forward declaration : class Creature;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Hero.h` and `Creature.h` include each other: you have a cyclic dependency. When `Hero.h` includes `Creature.h` and `Creature.h` tries to include `Hero.h` again, `HERO_H_` is already defined, and thus nothing gets inserted (if you removed the include guards, you would get an endless include cycle which is no good either).

However, it seems that `Creature.h` does not actually use `Hero.h`, so you can just remove this header. If you later do need something from the header, you may very well get away with a *forward declaration*. For more on this, see the C++ FAQ entry ["How can I create two classes that both know about each other?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/forward-decl.html).